# Bad regexp not catch surname, please fix it

Tags: ruby, regex

Regexp

```
@src = "Jack Donovan"

@namerx = "(Jack|Betty|Christine|Michael)(.+?)(\w+)"
/@namerx/.match(@src)
```

The result NIL! WHY Regexp is bad? My Komodo RX toolKit says regexp is okay.

[Picture of RX Toolkit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTdPG.png)

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to do? BTW, to define a regex, use `/.../` notation. Also, check [this demo](https://ideone.com/2JevGi).

Comment: Working for me: https://regex101.com/r/zkT4S4/1

Answer (score 1):

Your regex was alright. it's how you transferred it to ruby was wrong.

```
@namerx = /(Jack|Betty|Christine|Michael)(.+?)(\w+)/
@namerx.match(@src) # => #<MatchData "Jack Donovan" 1:"Jack" 2:" " 3:"Donovan">
```

Comment: So I should put / to start and end to string of @namerx? And thats all?

Comment: @Denis: that makes it a regex literal, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to ignore one or more whitespace characters between first and second group, you need to do something like the following:

```
/Jack|Betty|Christine|Michael)\s+(\w+)/
```

If you're wanting to match only a single whitespace, you need to do :

```
/(Jack|Betty|Christine|Michael)\s(\w+)/
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yeah, I just double checked on rubular - it's too early and I'm not on enough coffee yet.

Comment: Cool. I'll remove my comment now then :)